# How can I add a unique number for each output from SPLIT in same formula - Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a row of text on cell K2,
on Y2 I have this formula;

That Split K2 values into several rows, replaces a special character for a twitter link, add together different html text together and here's where I'm struggling, adding a unique id to act as a # anchor link on my page.

`=ArrayFormula("<blockquote id=""quote-"&COUNTA(SPLIT(K2, CHAR(10)))&""" class=""wp-block-quote""><p>" & SPLIT(K2, CHAR(10)) & "</p><cite>" & A2 & "</cite></blockquote><br><div class=""container""><div class=""copy-text tweet-s""> <a href=""https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(K2, CHAR(10)) &", by "&A2&" - aabb"&"&hashtags="&J2," ","%20"),"'","%27"),"(","%28"),")","%29"),".","%2E") & """><i class=""fa fa-twitter""></i> Tweet it</a></div></div>")`

How can I get the the blockquote to generate a unique id for each quote, ideally quote-1 for the first splitted cell, and quote-2 and so on.
(current formula only spits out each split-cell with same id of "quote-3" as its the number of quotes)

K2 cell value example;
`Quote that is long number one`
`Quote that is shorter with a tagline`
`Quote with a joke inside it`

Where the results today of formula split out each quote as follows;
`"<blockquote id=""**quote-3**"" class=""wp-block-quote""><p>Quote that is long number one</p><cite>Artist</cite></blockquote><br><div class=""container""><div class=""copy-text tweet-s""> <a href=""https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=There%27s%20nothing%20wrong%20with%20having%20a%20tree%20as%20a%20friend%2E,%20by%20Bob%20Ross%20-%20Artpracticed%2Ecom%20&hashtags=artist,inspiration""><i class=""fa fa-twitter""></i> Tweet it</a></div></div>"`

next cell;
`"<blockquote id=""**quote-3**"" class=""wp-block-quote""><p>Quote that is shorter with a tagline</p><cite>Artist</cite></blockquote><br><div class=""container""><div class=""copy-text tweet-s""> <a href=""https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=There%27s%20nothing%20wrong%20with%20having%20a%20tree%20as%20a%20friend%2E,%20by%20Bob%20Ross%20-%20Artpracticed%2Ecom%20&hashtags=artist,inspiration""><i class=""fa fa-twitter""></i> Tweet it</a></div></div>"`

and rest of cell in same order. But where I'd want the `blockquote id="quote-1"` for first cell that is split, then next quote (above) would have `blockquote id="quote-2"` and so forth.

Comment: `I have a row of text on cell K2`. Would you please edit your question to provide an example of the text in cell K2, and an example of the desired output after the formula runs successfully.